# What is the proper way to share a list between class instances?

Tags: python, class

I have this example code

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]

class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(my_list)

    def add(self, num):
        my_list.append(num)



class_list = []
for x in range(5):
    class_list.append(A())
    class_list[x].add("class_%s" % (x))
    print class_list[x]
```

The non-example code of mine is more complicated, but the idea is that I have multiple instances of the classes off doing a "thing". The global `my_list` is utilized across all instances. When certain logic is met within a class, that instance will modify the list. The rest of the classes will utilize that list to perform their logic as well. Any instance can add to the list, and all instances should be able to utilize the updated value.

Now in this example, the `my_list` is shared, but is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: As a side note: Always, always use `class A(object):`, not `class A:`, in Python 2.x. Otherwise, you're creating classic classes, which have a variety of quirks and misfeatures, some of which come dangerously close to what you want to do here.

Comment: Why not pass the global list in as an argument to each instances `__init__`? Lists are passed by reference, so each instance can read and modify the list (assuming you're not dealing with concurrency).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class attribute is *usually* better than a global, because then they're just sharing it with each other, rather than with everyone in the world.

To do that, move the `my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]` line under the `class A:`, and change every reference to `my_list` to `self.my_list` or `A.my_list`:

```
class A(object):
    shared_list = []
    def add(self, num):
        self.my_list.append(num)
```

---

However, an instance attribute is *often* even better. If you assign the same list to a bunch of different variables, it's still just one list; changing it affects all those variables. So, you can do something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, shared_list):
        self.shared_list = shared_list
    def add(self, num):
        self.shared_list.append(num)
```

Now it's up to the code that uses the `A` objects to decide whether to give them all the same list. You can even create 20 instances that share one list, and 10 that share a different one:

```
list1 = []
group1 = [A(list1) for _ in range(20)
list2 = []
group2 = [A(list2) for _ in range(10)
```

---

The question is whether the caller, or the `A` class, or nobody at all is the one who should be making the decision of how "shared" the list is. The answer is different for different applications, so it's hard to give an answer for an abstract example with names like `A` and `my_list`.

Comment: Faster gun in the West today :-)

Comment: @mgilson: That's what happens when I'm working on a project with an edit-compile-debug cycle of seriously over a minute, like this was back in the stone ages or something. (And now my younger self will smack me with a stack of fanfold paper with compile errors from an overnight batch job.)

Comment: If I utilize the second option presented, does that mean if I update `list1`, all of the `group1` instances have access to the new list?

Comment: @Python Noob: As abarnert said "If you assign the same list to a bunch of different variables, it's still just one list; changing it affects all those variables." But don't take our word for it, test it for yourself! :)